# How to make header cover entire page length?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a header cover the contents and span the entire page length? When I use this css

```
#header {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #015367;
}

#login {
    color: #b92c2c;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin-left: 18em;
    position: relative;
    top: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#search-form {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 15em;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
}

.lfloat {
    float: left;
}

.rfloat {
    float: right;
}
```

with this html

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="page-nav" class="rfloat">
            <a id="login" class="lfloat" href="/login">login</a>
            <form id="search-form" class="rfloat" action="search.py" method="get">
                <input id="searchbox" type="text" name="q" placeholder="search"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I get this result (in firefox)
[image: html+css result]

What do I need to change to get a proper header (like stackoverflow, facebook, etc)?

Comment: Do you need the header to span the page length, or contain the login form?

Comment: Both. Right now the header doesn't touch the edges of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `float` for the elements inside `#header`, then you only need to add this.

```
#header {
    background-color: #015367;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Before overflow:hidden**

[image]

Notice the black border, the `#header` isn't wrapping the contents.

**After overflow:hidden**

[image]

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/vpRc2/

Adjust the `top` so that elements are positioned the way you like, `position:relative;` has no use here, just use `floats` and `margins`.

Comment: okay so the header wraps the contents but how do I get it to span the entire page length? The header is a little to the right of the left edge of the page and isn't even close to touching the right side.

Comment: Don't use `inline-block`, the `#header` must wrap contents and must keep its original display which is `block`, this way, you don't need to set a width, since a div normally takes all the width. Update the codes your using so I can test.

Comment: @student One thing that I really didn't understand is why you used `float:left;` with a big `margin-left` and `float:right;` with a big `margin-right`, check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/GnYFv/

Comment: when i get rid of inline-block, the background-color doesn't show.

Comment: I know and thats why you need to add `overflow:hidden;` . Also you must add `body { margin:0; padding:0; }`

Comment: if you post your comments as an answer I'll accept it as the answer. You've been a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS to zero out the margin on the body:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/yPGYb/).

I would also suggest you remove your `position` and `top` properties from `#login` and `#search-form`, and use `margin` to position them instead.

Answer (score 1):

inline-block ??

```
#header {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to just extend the header box to contain the login form.
The effect you are experiencing is due to the use of floating elements in the header tag. Floated elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document, this is why the parent element cannot detect their actual occupation of space.

There is an easy fix to this just add a `overflow:hidden;` to the style of header div. This would fix the problem but it is not considered to be the right way to do it. The overflow is not meant to be used in such a manner. Instead my advice to you is to use the "clearfix" method.

Here is link for the actual code: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

All you have to do is to add this code as a class to the header element.

I hope this helps :)